# Sequence of Points as a Set

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

If one has as a set $\{ x_n \}$ defined by a sequence

$x_n = (-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1}$,

is it the case that this set is neither connected nor compact?  (The topology is the Euclidean one).

Edit: I've just thought about this more and suppose that is cannot be connected anyway because all the numbers in this sequence are rational numbers.  Also the rational numbers are not even locally compact, whereas $\mathbb{R}$ is at least locally compact.

Comment: **Hint :** The set is not connected from the moment that the sequence has to different values. It can be compact in general, but in your specific case, it is not : indeed $1$ is in the closure of the set but is not in the set.

Comment: Yes, $-1$ is also in the closure without being in the set.  Is there an example of a sequence which could be both compact and connected as a set?

Comment: Take any constant sequence :)

Comment: Is there some example which is non-trivial?

Comment: Not for connectedness. For compacity, yes : take a sequence such that $a_0=0$ and $a_n= 1/n$ for $n \geq 1$ for example.

Comment: Does that mean that in general any set (not necessarily a sequence) which has points in the closure which are not in the set itself is non-compact?

Comment: @Tom Compact sets in the Euclidean topology are also closed, i.e., equal to their closure.

Answer (score 1):

Defining $A=\{(-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1}\mid n \in \Bbb N\}$, we see that $1 \in \overline{A}$ (take the terms with even $n$, these converge to $1$), and also $-1 \in \overline{A}$ (odd terms...), but neither are in $A$.

$A$ compact implies $A$ closed, and $A$ is not closed, so ...

A connected subset of $\Bbb R$ is either empty, a singleton, or uncountable. $A$ is countable and not empty or a singleton..